# Functions, sets, isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

Determine the functions $ f:\mathbb{R}^{*}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ for which $ G=\left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
x & f(x)\\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}|x\in \mathbb{R}^{*} \right \} $ is closed under multiplication of matrices from $ M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $. In this case, prove that groups $ (G,\cdot ) $ and $ (\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*},\cdot ) $ are isomorphic.

I think that $ f(x)\cdot f(y)=x\cdot f(y)+f(x) $, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Are you sure that you're proving that $(G,\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}_+^*,\cdot)$ and not $(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ has to satisfy $f(xy)=xf(y)+f(x).$  For $y=-1$ we have

$$f(-x)=xf(-1)+f(x).$$ For $x=-1$ we have

$$f(-y)=-f(y)+f(-1).$$ That is

$$f(-x)=-f(x)+f(-1).$$ Thus we have

$$\begin{cases}f(-x)-f(x)&=xf(-1)\\f(-x)+f(x)&=f(-1)\end{cases}$$ Solving the system we get $f(x)=\frac{f(-1)}{2}(1-x).$

Comment: This answer isn't *quite* complete.  It has not proven that $f(-1)$ is free.   It could be that $f(-1)$ must be $7$ say.  However, it is clear from the functional equation that that the $f(-1)$ will be a common factor of all terms, and thus the equation doesn't determine it.  That is, any scalar multiple of any solution is also a solution.  We can "simplify" to just $f(x) = \alpha(1-x)$ for some real number $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x & f(x) \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
y & f(y) \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
xy& x\cdot f(y)+f(x) \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)=A.$$
So, $A\in G \Longleftrightarrow f(xy)=x\cdot f(y)+f(x)$.

By the mfl's argument, $f$ has to satisfy
$$f(x)=\dfrac{f(-1)}{2}(1-x).$$

Comment: Plugging in $x = y = 1$ leads us to conclude $f(1) = 0$

Comment: Plug in y = 0, see what you get.

Comment: @user3294068 $y\in\Bbb{R}^{*}$ so $y$ can't be zero.